# Checking variable outside of its scope

Tags: javascript, android, typescript, react-native, apollo

In my code I want to execute a query conditionally and then check its loading variable inside the template, but only if the query is executed and don't want to have any TypeScript errors in my file. How do I check this variable which might or might not exist in its context?

I am using Apollo GraphQL.

```
if( executeMyQuery )
{
    const {
        data, loading: loadingQuery
    } = useQuery( MyQuery );
}

return (
    <View>
        { /* ... some code ... */ }
        { executeMyQuery && loadingQuery ?
            <Text>Query is loading...</Text>
            { /* ... some code ... */ }
        : null }
    </View>
);
```

TypeScript says: `Cannot find name 'loadingQuery'.`

Comment: You are not allowed to call `useQuery` hook inside a conditional statement. See the docs https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it using the `skip` parameter by changing

```
if( executeMyQuery )
{
    const {
        data, loading: loadingQuery
    } = useQuery( MyQuery );
}
```

To

```
const {
    data, loading: loadingQuery
} = useQuery( MyQuery, {
    skip: executeMyQuery,
} );
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [dependent queries](https://react-query.tanstack.com/guides/dependent-queries)

```
const {
     data, loading: loadingQuery
} = useQuery( MyQuery,    {
 // The query will not execute until the userId exists
 enabled: executeMyQuery,
   }
);

return (
    <View>
        { /* ... some code ... */ }
        { executeMyQuery && loadingQuery ?
            <Text>Query is loading...</Text>
            { /* ... some code ... */ }
        : null }
    </View>
);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! However, it seems that the 'enabled' parameter is not recognized in my code

Comment: 'enabled' does not exist in type 'QueryHookOptions'

Comment: I am using Apollo GraphQL instead of React Query

Comment: Sorry, in this case you should use useLazyQuery.

Comment: Instead of `enabled`, I needed to use `skip` :)